# Loading a big script into neo4j IDE

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a very large .cypher file of 20K lines. When I use the IDE it will only accept 400 lines at a time. this is very long winded. Is there a way I can get neo4j to accept the cypher file in one go, or alternatively, is there another format I can use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried the neo4j-shell? You can usually paste it in there, or pipe it into the shell if you are on Linux/OSX...

Comment: thanks - I am running it on a windows 8.1 PC, and I don't have the neo4j-shell installed :(

Comment: rick, you can download the zip version and it should include the neo4j-shell

Answer (score 3):

A 20k line cypher file which contains only a single statement is not likely to be parsed successfully.

I recommend breaking it up into smaller statements separated by a Semicolon and using Neo4jShell -file with it.

If you installed Neo4j Desktop on Windows you can find the steps to run the shell here: http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2013/11/29/neo4j-the-case-of-windows-neo4j-desktop-and-the-invisible-text/

Comment: Does the shell have a log file? The script is failing but there is no output even when run as administrator.